# redirect_to method propagates DELETE http action throughout nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

The above is the result of deleted comment. Notice that as you delete a comment, the comment's parent post is also deleted through `redirect_to`

```
Started DELETE "/posts/19/comments/30" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-03 01:10:43 -0800
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"19", "id"=>"30"}
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "30"]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "19"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "30"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 30]]
   (7.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/19
Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 8.4ms)


Started DELETE "/posts/19" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-03 01:10:43 -0800
Processing by PostsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"19"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "19"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "19"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 19
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  [["id", 19]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)


Started DELETE "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-03 01:10:43 -0800
Processing by PagesController#home as JS
  Rendered pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 39.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

---

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put "soft_destroy"
  end

  resources :comments do
    member do
      get "reply"
      post "create_reply"
      put "soft_destroy"
    end
  end
end
```

comments controller

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to @post
end
```

delete link on view file

```
= link_to "delete", [@post, comment], method: :DELETE, remote: true
```

Post model

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

Comment model

```
belongs_to :post
```

Is there a reason why DELETE html verb propagates on posts controller as well? Rather than just calling `show` action?

Comment: What happens if you change the redirect in your CommentsController to: redirect_to post_url(@post)?

Comment: Same thing happens with that, but I fixed the problem. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by delete link on view file

```rb
= link_to "delete", [@post, comment], method: :DELETE, remote: true
```

For some reason, ajax request with method DELETE seems to propagate beyond the first DELETE request.

I removed `remote: true` and it now makes a GET request rather than DELETE request to the post.

```rb
= link_to "delete", [@post, comment], method: :DELETE
```

I still don't understand why this is happening though.

Comment: Thats a really interesting situation (as annoying as it is), what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Also have a look at the network traffic in your debugging tools, is JS  initiating the second request?